# Use of undeclared type when calling insertNewObjectForEntityForName(_ :, inManagedObjectContext: )

Tags: swift, debugging, core-data

I'm playing around with code from objC's Core Data book but have come up against a weird bug when attempting to insert a new object into the managed object context using the following code which is an extension on NSManagedObjectContext:

```
/**
 Helper method - avoids manual downcast result of an insert action and entity does not have to be referenced by name

 - returns: new entity (NSManagedObject)
 */
public func insertObject<A: ManagedObject where A: ManagedObjectType>() -> A {
    NSLog("\(A.entityName) - \(self)")
    guard let obj = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(A.entityName, inManagedObjectContext: self) as? A else
    { fatalError("Failed to insert entity into context") }
    return obj
}
```

The insert fails and an object is not instantiated. Inspecting the managed object context (self in this case) gives the following debug information:

```
Printing description of self:
expression produced error: /var/folders/__/c3n7c0bd35v5f7qxv11gcg280000gn/T/lldb/25862/expr10.swift:1:46: error: use of undeclared type 'CoreData'
$__lldb__DumpForDebugger(Swift.UnsafePointer<CoreData.NSManagedObjectContext>(bitPattern: 0x116b90fa0).memory)
                                             ^~~~~~~~
/var/folders/__/c3n7c0bd35v5f7qxv11gcg280000gn/T/lldb/25862/expr10.swift:1:45: note: while parsing this '<' as a type parameter bracket
$__lldb__DumpForDebugger(Swift.UnsafePointer<CoreData.NSManagedObjectContext>(bitPattern: 0x116b90fa0).memory)
```

Any ideas? I'm a Core Data newbie so I'm more than clueless!

Comment: Have you added `import CoreData`?

Comment: Yep - CoreData present and correct. I'm not getting any compiler errors which suggests the library is present and correct at least at compile time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - found the solution. An object was being created but it couldn't be cast to the NSManagedObject subclass as I'd failed to correctly set the class and class module for the entity definition within Xcode's data model definition. I've no idea why I got such a cryptic error message however It reminds me of working with Swift 1.0...!

[image: Xcode core data model pane]

Comment: I would carefully check things are set up correctly in your data model (see above) as errors in that area caused me no end of problems. The issue seems to be because of Swift's tight adherence to name spaces.